# Cannot install packages from Github in R

Tags: r, github, devtools, remotes

this week I formatted my SSD and everything was fine, but now... when I am trying to install a package from Github, using both packages: devtools and remotes. But I am getting the following error.

```
> devtools::install_github('dcomtois/summarytools')
Error: Failed to install 'summarytools' from GitHub:
  failed setting cipher list: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH

> remotes::install_github('dcomtois/summarytools')
Error: Failed to install 'summarytools' from GitHub:
  failed setting cipher list: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
```

R session:

```
> session_info()
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
 os       Pop!_OS 20.10               
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu           
 ui       RStudio                     
 language en_US:en                    
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       America/Sao_Paulo           
 date     2021-03-01                  

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package       * version date       lib source        
 assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cachem          1.0.4   2021-02-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 callr           3.5.1   2020-10-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 cli             2.3.1   2021-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 crayon          1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 desc            1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 devtools      * 2.3.2   2020-09-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 digest          0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ellipsis        0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 evaluate        0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 fs              1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 glue            1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 htmltools       0.5.1.1 2021-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 knitr           1.31    2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 lifecycle       1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 magrittr        2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 memoise         2.0.0   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgbuild        1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 pkgload         1.2.0   2021-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 prettyunits     1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 processx        3.4.5   2020-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 ps              1.6.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 purrr           0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 R6              2.3.0   2018-10-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 remotes       * 2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 RevoUtils     * 11.0.2  2020-08-12 [2] local         
 RevoUtilsMath * 11.0.0  2020-08-12 [2] local         
 rlang           0.4.10  2020-12-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rmarkdown       2.7     2021-02-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 rprojroot       2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 sessioninfo     1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 testthat        3.0.2   2021-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 usethis       * 2.0.1   2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 withr           2.4.1   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 xfun            0.21    2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
 yaml            2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
```

PS: sorry for my bad English, not my mother language :)

Comment: I can download the package without any errors with `devtools`. I am on R.version 4.0.3 and `packageVersion('devtools')` is 2.3.2

Comment: I've just updated, but still facing the same problem

Comment: I don't see *magick* in your list of installed packages... It is a requirement for *summarytools* to work.